# Does ethanol react with potassium to form potassium ethanolate and hydrogen gas?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

I'm finding information in Google with the keyword (C2H5OH + K) to find the reaction between $\ce{C2H5OH}$ and $\ce{K}$ and found very little information about it. Just 2-3 related results with contradictory pieces of information.

[The first one gave](http://www.webqc.org/balance.php?reaction=K+%2B+C2H5OH+%3D+KOH+%2B+C2H5)

$$
\ce{K + C2H5OH -> KOH + C2H5},
$$

[the second one gave](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140103231122AA62uyX)

$$
\ce{2C2H5OH + 2K -> 2C2H5OK + H2},
$$

and [the third one gave](http://forum.xumuk.ru/index.php?showtopic=17664)

$$
\ce{C2H5OH + KOH -> C2H5OK + H2O}
$$

There are no trusted public sources so I'm very baffled. I think that $\ce{C2H5OH}$ will react with $\ce{K}$ to form $\ce{C2H5OK}$ because it looks like the reaction with $\ce{Na}$. But I'm not sure and just want to find a trusted source. Can anyone confirm the true result for this reaction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can view water as the simplest alcohol, and indeed, water reacts with all of the Group 1 metals to form hydrogen gas and the corresponding metal hydroxide according to the following equation

$\ce{2M + 2HOH -> 2MOH + H2}$

where $\ce{M}$ is the metal.

The same reaction occurs with simple alcohols to produce the corresponding metal alkoxide and hydrogen gas

$\ce{2M + 2ROH -> 2MOR + H2}$

As you increase the hydrocarbon portion of the alcohol, or reduce accessibility to the $\ce{OH}$ portion of the alcohol (*e.g.* make the alcohol less like water), you slow down the rate of the reaction.

[Here is a nice link](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group1/reacth2o.html) that compares and discusses the relative reactivities of the Group 1 metals with water.

Comment: Yes, and that's a standard way to dispose of extra Na, K and other alakali metals, since it's a bit less vigorous then dropping them in H20. ;-) See http://www.nap.edu/openbook.php?record_id=4911&page=165.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik True, but let's not forget this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY7mTCMvpEM :D